# Pinmode register in lpc2468

Tags: arm7

Will a **PINMODE register in lpc2468 affect the status of an input pin** i.e can we enable

an internal pull up for an input pin,or it is only possible for output pins.

Answer (score 4):

Pull-up and pull-down apply to I/O used as input, not output. Inputs shouldn't remain floating, so you either

1. drive them with a push-pull output to a logical low or high level
2. use external pull-up or pull-down
3. use internal pull-up or pull-down

Pull-up/pull-down will set the input to a valid level if it would otherwise be floating. The second and third option are normally used with either open drain outputs (usually with pull-ups) or with switches/pushbuttons.

Remember that the datasheet will in general only give you device-specific information. Data which is common to all members of a microcontroller family can be found in that family's user guide.

**Further reading**
[LPC24xx User Guide](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10237.pdf)
[LPC2468 Datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC2468.pdf)